# Avocado tree from seed

Tags: trees, plant-health, indoors

I have an almost one year old tree from a seed.  It keeps dropping leaves as new growth happens and I can't figure out why. It only holds 3 or 4 leaves at a time. It is in a pot with good potting soil. As a new sapling it wilted in direct sunlight so moved it to indirect light where it was doing well. This December I had to bring it in to my Florida Room because of unusual cold in NE Florida.

Now that it’s back outside the bottom leaves are browning and falling off. Is it going to live? It has beginnings of new growth at the top.

Comment: Where do you live?  Please post a picture.  How much light are you giving it? I suspect you are not giving it enough light, but I need more information

Comment: Inside or out side ? I had a couple about 10 ft tall ; outside about 7 months and inside the other 5 , they grew great out side then faded inside . They never tried to make fruit. There are better house plants.

Comment: I've had this same exact problem. I tried replanting it, and I noticed the roots were all moldy. I think it's due to a fungal infection. The plant eventually died.